# Complement of an n-simplex in a triangulated n-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, spheres, triangulation, simplicial-complex

Let $\Sigma^n$ be a finite simplicial complex homeomorphis to $S^n$. Is it true that, after removing one $n$-simplex, the rest is a triangulated disc? (By that I mean a~simplicial complex homeomorphic to $D^n$)

---

My attempts: First I thought it is obvious; then I realised that an analogy is not true in the continuous category (the complement of the Alexander horned 3-disc in $S^3$ is wild). But still, if $\sigma$ is an $n$-simplex in a finite triangulation $\Sigma^n$, then $(\Sigma^n, \sigma)$ has the homotopy extension property. Note sure how to continue..

---

**After edit**: The question is partially motivated by this:

> Is "recognising a triangulated disc" a decidable problem?

If the above conjecture is true, then the undecidability of sphere-recognition in dimension $\geq 5$ implies the undecidability of disc recognition.

Comment: I can think of a proof scheme using the Brown-Masur theorem, aka the Generalized Schoenflies Theorem, namely: try to prove is that the boundary of the simplex has a collar neighborhood on the outside; in other words, when the interior of the simplex is removed, the boundary of the simplex has a collar neighborhood in what remains. This will be enough, because clearly the boundary has a collar neighborhood on the inside, and so the hypotheses of the theorem are satisfied.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove a $n$-simplex, the result is a deformation retracts of $S^n$-point which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the stereographic projection.

Comment: But is there a simple argument that the result is a manifold with boundary? (A deformation-retract of $R^n$ doesn't need to be...)

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions one can ask (and answer) along the lines of your question. The more natural one is:

Let $M$ be a simplicial complex homeomorphic to $S^n$, let $\Delta$ be an **open** $n$-simplex in $M$. Is it true that $M- \Delta$ is **PL homeomorphic** to $D^n$ (the standard closed $n$-disk with the standard PL structure).

One can also ask a weaker question (and this is what you seem to be asking, except you are not making it clear if your simplex is open or closed), namely, if $M- \Delta$ is **homeomorphic** to the closed $n$-dimensional ball $D^n$.

I will answer the second question, but with a bit more care, the same proof will go through for the first one. A good reference for all this is

[RS] Rourke and Sanderson "Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology".

I will try to consistently use $\Delta$ for an open n-dimensional simplex and $\bar\Delta$ for its closure. I will use the notation 
$$
A=\{x\in R^n : 1/2\le |x|\le 1\} 
$$
for the $n$-dimensional annulus and $D^n$ for a closed unit ball in $R^n$ (centered at the origin).

1. First of all, if $N$ is a regular neighborhood of a simplex $\bar\Delta$ in a triangulated manifold $M$, then $N$ is PL homeomorphic to $D^n$. In order to prove this, first verify that $N - \Delta\cong A$ (Corollary 3.18 of [RS]). Then construct a PL homeomorphism $N\to D^n$ by sending $\bar\Delta$ to the ball of radius $1/2$ and then extend the boundary map to $N - \Delta$ sending it to the annulus $A$.
2. Given this, the problem reduces to the following: Let $\Delta_2$ be an open facet of a triangulated manifold $M$ homeomorphic to the $n$-dimensional sphere $S^n= R^n \cup \{\infty\}$, let $\bar\Delta_1 \subset \Delta_2$ be a closed simplex. We need to show that $M- \Delta_1$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$. To prove this, take a homeomorphism which sends $\bar\Delta_2$ to a unit ball $D^n\subset R^n$ and takes $\bar\Delta_1$ to a concentric ball $\frac{1}{2}D^n$ of half the radius (see Part 1). 
   Now, I leave it to you to check that $$R^{n}\cup\{\infty\} - int(\frac{1}{2}D^n)$$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$. (Hint: Use the inversion.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, Moishe. I think I kind of understand 1. As for the rest, I'm still confused, unfortunately. How did you use 1. in 2.? What do you mean by open facet in this context? If a homeomorphism takes $\overline{\Delta}_2$ to $D^n$, why is it the this homeomorphism can be extended to a self-homeomorphism of $S^n$ (if you claim that)?...

Comment: @PeterFranek: A facet in a simplicial complex is a maximal face; in our case, this is a simplex of maximal dimension. Open simplex is define in the 2nd paragraph.To define an extension, you notice that, by Part 1, everything is taking place in a topological ball, $\bar\Delta_2$. Thus, you can radially extend a radial homeomorphism $\bar\Delta_1\to \frac{1}{2}D^n$ to a self-homeomorphism of $\bar\Delta_2$ which fixes the boundary pointwise. Then extend by the identity to the rest of the sphere.

Comment: (So $\overline{\Delta_2}$ is the regular neighborhood of the simplex $\overline{\Delta_1}$ of the initial triangulation?) Anyway, my main problem is this: how do you know that there exists a homeomorphism $S^n\to S^n$ that takes $\overline{\Delta_2}$ into a disc $D^n$ that is embedded *in a nice way*, not something like the Alexander horned ball?